# Create pdf java from base64

Tags: java, pdf, itext, base64

I am exploring usage of iText maven dependency to generate a pdf from the below code.

```
try {
     
Document document = new Document();
OutputStream outputStream = 
    new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\ImageTester\\samplePDF.pdf"));
    
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
    //Open the document
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("Hello world ");

    //Close document and outputStream.
    document.close();
    outputStream.close();

    System.out.println("Pdf created successfully.");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Maven:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

This above works fine and generate the PDF. However, I have a use-case where I am sent Base64 encoded String that needs to be saved as PDF. How do I this? Converting the Base64 to a byte array and writing that to the outputStream generates the a corrupted PDF.

```
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64String);
outputStream.write(bytes);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
```

Comment: *Converting the Base64 to a byte array and writing that to the outputStream* - yes, that's basically what you have to do. If this doesn't work, the next question would be what does the Base64 look like?

Comment: `Base64.Decoder.wrap` would be better (there's no need to read the whole file into memory)

Comment: Doing so leaves a corrupted pdf saying 'We can't open this file'. I am able to decode and save it to a .tiff fine. Just not PDF. The Base64 is a report so it contains some image formatting as well besides text.

Comment: Well it would be useful to see a small example of one of these base64 strings

Comment: Unfortunately I can't paste the Base64 here but when I try to decode it through base64decode.org it gives me some special characters hinting something is wierd with this incoming Base64. Uploaded snippet snapshot here: https://ibb.co/9yz4D45

Comment: That's not really helpful at all, since there's no knowing what you told that site about how to decode it. It *looks* as though you might have told it to decode it *as a string*. That's not going to work if it's a pdf file. You should paste *a* pdf file that reproduces the problem but with no sensitive info

Comment: Actually I'm getting confused: *I have a use-case where I am sent Base64 encoded String that needs to be saved as PDF.* If it's an encoded *string* why is it base64-encoded? Base64 is for binary content

Comment: I get it as a part of an interface. It starts with this `^IM^TIFF^Base64^JVBERi0xLjcNC.....blah`. I am able to decode and save it as .tiff however I would like that option to save as a PDF if it has multiple pages in the same report.

Comment: You can't "save as" a pdf. You need to take the tif and encapsulate the image(s) in a pdf document you created